# LACCDB record locking file does not close

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a problem with my back end data file staying open, LACCDB file stays open. I have narrowed it down to a few lines of code that is causing the problem. I have tried a number of solutions but nothing works for me. The only option is to close the front end but that's not practical.

I want to copy this BE file but cant if the LACCDB file is open. No other users. I have tried deleting both the Query and the table(linked) but that still does not resolve the issue. Running MS Access 2007 and tried on various PC's. I have also tried moving the ACCDB file from Mapped drive to local drive.

The code:

```
Function TestMyLinks()
MyQuery="Test-Filter"
MyTable="Test"
MyCriteria = "[TestId]> 1"
MyCriteria = "SELECT [" & MyTable & "].*" & " FROM [" & MyTable & "] Where " & MyCriteria

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, MyQuery    'Delete new query.
Set qdf = DataDb.CreateQueryDef(MyQuery, MyCriteria) ' Create new query
DoCmd.Close acQuery, MyQuery, acSaveYesDoCmd.Close acTable, "Test", acSaveYes

' This following code does not make any difference
'DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Test-Filter"
'DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Test"
'DoCmd.TransferDatabase TransferType:=acLink, _
'        DatabaseType:="Microsoft Access", _
'        DatabaseName:="C:\MyClock\Test.accdb", _
'        ObjectType:=acTable, _
'        Source:="Attendance", _
'        Destination:="Attendance"
'Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True
'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompactDatabase
'DBEngine.CompactDatabase "C:\MyClock\Test.accdb", "C:\MyClock\TestA.accdb" ' This fails1 as file locked
End Function
```

I have tried closing the tables using code:

```
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Test-Filter", acSaveNo
DoCmd.Close acTable, "Test", acSaveNo
```

I have also tried as per another post to release memory:

```
'release memory
qdf.Close 'i changed qdef to qdf here and below
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run this from the front-end db? You should have a separate db with no tables or forms linked to the database. When all front-ends are closed that laccdb file should disappear and you can compact your backend db from this new unlinked db.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I was trying to run from Front End and as all tables were closed (so I think) was expecting the laccdb to automatically close. Unfortunately that's my problem. The only way of releasing the laccdb was to close the Front End.

Comment: You can't just close the tables - you have to "delete" them. Remove all linked tables. You can store the table names in a local table - then run them though a loop to relink afterwards.